# Problems with trying to merge mysql databases running off MAMP and Homebrew installations

Tags: php, mysql

I set up a database a few months ago as a bit of an experiment and it sits happily on my hard drive having been set up with Homebrew.

Then a few days ago I was looking at a project and remembered MAMP as an option to provide a localised service. I installed and I have the situation where phpMyAdmin points at a new database.

I'm left with a situation where I can login by CLI to the old database when what I really want is MAMP to point to that database so I can do some admin work with PHPMyAdmin rather than the one I've just created. Can I just merge both the Homebrew and MAMP set ups?

If it sounds like I'm very new to this, yes, I am.

Comment: You probably will have to grant additional permissions inside the MySQL servers but generally speaking sure, such access it network transparent, so any client can access any database server provided it has network access and the required permissions inside that database server. It is irrelevant _how_ that server is operated (so by what software stack). Well, strictly speaking that database server has to be up for this, so running, obviously.

Comment: If you want to operate _both_ database servers at the same time then you actually have to start both servers. Not sure if you want that, sounds like a strange setup. Instead I would indeed suggest to kind of "merge" the two. Easiest would be to export the database from the old setup and import it into the new setup, so into the new database server. Exporting and importing database tables is well documented, you will also find many tutorials about that. Just try around, you can always repeat your steps if you get stuck on the way.

Comment: I definitely don't want two databases, just one from which I can access the tables if needed.

Comment: Keep in mind that a mysql database server can contain multiple databases, independent from each other. So absolutely nothing speaks against importing that "old" database alongside the "new" one. You can even make queries over _both_ databases, if you really have to, though that is not common.

Answer (score 0):

My decision was to junk the brew version by

```
brew uninstall mysql
```

Okay, lost a little data, but it was a testbed.

Added the path of MAMP to .zshrc

```
echo 'export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

And then away.

> mysql -u root -p